# How to use withAvg but should nullify if soft deleted? laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables that are related. I am using `withAvg` to get the user's average of posts. But I don't why it still returning average values of posts, even I soft deleted all **Post**.

I know there are many existing related questions about this, but I can't find the exact and clean one.

My question is, how to exclude soft deleted posts upon using `withAvg`

---

**Code is,**

```
User::whereId(2)
    ->with('posts')
    ->withAvg('posts AS post_avg', 'counts')
    ->first();
```

The expected output should receive **null** in average

```
[
    {
        id: 2,
        user: 'Mauris vitae'
        post_avg: null <= all posts were soft deleted
        posts: [
            {
                title: 'Etiam enim purus, bibendum quis'
                deleted_at: '2021-07-14 15:42:18'
                ...
            }
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: can you show user model